# Web application server architecture: is it better to have one big server or many small servers?

Tags: database-design, server, architecture

I am creating the server architecture for my web application. I have a load balancer distributing requests to multiple servers.

Is it better to use one big server or multiple smaller servers?

Example:

1 server with 16GB of ram and 6 CPUs

or

4 Servers with 4 GB ram and 2 CPUs each.

My application sends many HTTP requests per second to the servers, but nothing that puts much stress on even the small servers.

Comment: This will really depend on the sizes. You say "many per second", that gives no idea if its 100 or a million. If your projected load wont stress the servers, then why are you splitting it up - is it for other non-performance considerations? And is this on prem or azure etc? Personally I would never do this with anything other than a cloud based architecture in this day and age, and scalability, redundancy etc is all pretty straightforward in those environments.

Comment: [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question??](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) Yes or no questions are seldom useful or asking for what is actually wanted. [ask] [Help] "better" means nothing in particular. What is your definition by which all would agree when evaluating a design & how are you stuck evaluating? PS This is way too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have very specific reason to Scale up (Single Big Server) , you must be scaling out (having redundant servers) with Auto-scale in place. This is most acceptable pattern now for couple of reasons.

**Avoid Single point of failure**

The main reason to scale out (having multiple servers) is to avoid single point of failure. In case of one big server , if that goes down your application goes with it.

**Scale out benefits**

- Instant and continuous availability
- No limit to hardware capacity
- Cost can be tied to use
- You’re not stuck always paying for peak demand
- Built-in redundancy
- Easy to size and resize properly to your needs

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple small servers can have following advantages over big one

1. You can reduce  single point of failure. If you use one big server
   and if it fails then all your users will be effecting with it. With
   multiple small servers, Load balancer monitor unhealthy instances
   and it stop sending new requests to the unhealthy one. Eventually
   you can attach more instances to elb using auto scale.
2. Using auto scale you can scale up and down no of workers (instances) as per the requests which receives to your servers. You can optimizes the infra cost.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Start with "*many small servers*", then *measure, identify bottlenecks, adapt*.

---

**If**

1. there is no significant economical advantage of either option
2. the sum of performance and capabilities of the options is roughly equal
3. none of the options have a significant disadvantage (i.e. cpu can handle usage spikes in all cases)

**then**

you start with at least 2 servers, ideally 3 or a higher odd number of servers   if running apps that have roles that depend on quorum.

---

Having just 1 server is generally a bad idea from business continuity point of view, and in such scenario having a quick recovery plan is practically a must-have from the start.

The best answer specific to your situation depends on identifying what component of the web application requires the most performance. It will  become the 1st bottleneck when throwing more requests at the web app as you grow the website. You *may* find that actually best start would be to have 2 servers instead of the options you mentioned, as the bottleneck would happen later.

Since you tagged databases, expect them to be the first bottlenecks that need bigger servers. For example: relational databases, like MySQL, usually work best when using no more than 2-3 write/primary cluster servers. This is due to performance degradation caused by data synchronization overhead. Performance bottlenecks are usually easiest to address by scaling these up, along with dedicating entire servers to them.